# How to get indexOf proper className of targeted element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an target element which is a SVG which has two properties `baseVal` and `aniVal`, So I'm trying to get the proper `indexOf` the `className` from the SVG target element.

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.className.baseVal && e.target.className.baseVal.indexOf('close') > -1) {
        return;
    } else if (e.target.className && e.target.className.indexOf('close') > -1)
        $(e.target).closest(".popover").remove();
    $('.popover').each(function () {
        whatever the code;
    });
});
```

Comment: Debug your variable `e.target.className.baseVal` in javascript console then type `yourstring.indexOf('close')` in the console

Comment: @ThanhTrung `e.target.className.baseVal.indexOf('close')` the value comes `-1`
`e.target.className.baseVal` = `'ck ck-icon ck-button__icon`
the reason that to happens only at certain part and others works fine in `className.indexOf('close')`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: `e.target.className` returns a string (a space separated list of class names of the element), that string doesn't contain `baseVal` _property_.

Comment: @Teemu is right `e.target.className` is not an object to access with the dot

Comment: @Teemu except for when the target element is a SVG. [MDN on className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) says, _"className can also be an instance of [SVGAnimatedString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString) if the element is an SVGElement."_ - and that one does have a `baseVal` property.

Comment: @CBroe A nice catch!

Comment: But I am guessing that `SVGAnimatedString` does not have an `indexOf` method. So in case where you _have_ a `e.target.className.baseVal`, but that did not contain  `close`, your code goes into the else branch - and `e.target.className.indexOf` will now fail, because `className` is not a plain string here, but an `SVGAnimatedString` instance.

Comment: But your if-else logic is simply not correct here then. You go into the else branch assuming it must _not_ be an instance of `SVGAnimatedString` here - but it can still have been one, just one where the `baseVal` did not happen to contain `close`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className` on a "normal" HTML element is a plain string, only when you are dealing with an SVG target element, it will be an instance of [`SVGAnimatedString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString), which then has a `baseVal` property.

You tried to take that into account with your if/else already - but not entirely correctly. The value could still be an instance of `SVGAnimatedString`, but its baseVal might not contain `close` - in which case you go into the else branch, and there it tries to call `indexOf` on that `SVGAnimatedString`, which it does not posses.

You need to take your if condition apart into two separate checks here:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.className.baseVal !== undefined) {
      if (e.target.className.baseVal.indexOf('close') > -1) {
        return;
      }
    } else if (e.target.className && e.target.className.indexOf('close') > -1)
        $(e.target).closest(".popover").remove();
        $('.popover').each(function () {
           //whatever the code;
        });
    }
});
```

(Whether that new "inner" `if` still needs an else branch, depends on what you want to happen when the target element is an SVG, but did not contain `close`.)

---

Edit: modified check for the `baseVaL` property to `!== undefined`, because otherwise an *empty* baseVal would also make it go into the else branch.

Comment: Okay so the error also happen when the `baseVal` is  `" "` empty string,so i think anything empty may have `className` but not  `close` value in it.

Comment: Then try and make that into a dedicated check whether the property exists - `if (e.target.className.baseVal !== undefined)`

Comment: Thank you it worked :) i think i already made a proper way of conditioning it but got off tracked and just forgot to see how the loop was going, learned a few things not always having an `&` is good for checking conditions can also use better way of if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this would help?

```js
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('close')) {
       $(e.target).closest(".popover").remove();
    }
    $('.popover').each(function () {
       // whatever the code;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="close">Click 1 </button>
<button>Click 1 </button>
<button>Click 1 </button>
<button>Click 1 </button>
```